Ошибка : missing 1 required positional argument
Как исправить:
    @start_router.message(GetMessage.text)
    async def text(message: Message, state: FSMContext, album: List[Message]):
        data = await state.get_data()
        media_group = []
        media = message.media_group_id
        caption = message.caption
        command_d = data['command']
        photo = message.photo
        document = message.document
        video = message.video
        text = message.text
        
        if media:
            for index, msg in enumerate(album):
                if msg.photo:
                    file_id = msg.photo[-1].file_id
                elif msg.document:
                    file_id = msg.document.file_id
                elif msg.video:
                    file_id = msg.video.file_id
                else:
                    continue  # Пропустим, если ни один из типов не найден
        
                # Добавляем caption только к первому элементу
                if index == 0 and caption:
                    media_group.append((file_id, caption))
                else:
                    media_group.append(file_id)
        
            ms.add_handler(data["message_id"], command_d, None, None, None, None, media_group)
        
        elif photo:
            if caption:
                ms.add_message(data
    
["message_id"], command_d, caption, photo[-1].file_id)
        else:
            ms.add_message(data["message_id"], command_d, None, photo[-1].file_id)
    
    elif video:
        if caption:
            ms.add_message(data["message_id"], command_d, caption, None, None, video.file_id)
        else:
            ms.add_message(data["message_id"], command_d, None, None, None, video.file_id)
    
    elif document:
        if caption:
            ms.add_message(data["message_id"], command_d, caption, None, document.file_id)
        else:
            ms.add_message(data["message_id"], command_d, None, None, document.file_id)
    
    elif text:  # Обработка текстового сообщения
        ms.add_message(data["message_id"], command_d, text, None) 
    
    await state.clear()
    await message.answer('✅ <b>Сообщение сохранено</b>', parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=cl.back())

Ошибка:
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
                    ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: text() missing 1 required positional argument: 'album'


Заголовок значащий.
